# How to highlight every other row with %?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I highlight (i.e. change the background color) every other row with `%` in JavaScript? I was thinking about `if (i % 2 == 0)`. Does this work?

```
// declaring variables
var rows = 12;
var cols = 3;

document.write('<table border=2>');

for (var k = 0; k < head.length; k++) {
    // input the heading of the table
    document.write('<th>' + head[k] + '</th>');
}

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    document.write('<tr>' + 0 + '</tr>');

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        // don't know what to put in here
    } else {

    }

    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        document.write('<td>' + Table[i][j] + '</td>');
    }
}

document.write('</table>');
```

Comment: what do you mean by highlight?

Comment: *Does this work?* Why can't you try it and find out yourself?

Comment: Why would you want to? If by highlight you mean change the background color or something, just use CSS: `tr:nth-of-type(odd) td`.

Comment: Chris is my solution what you're hoping to do?

Comment: Sorry, it should be "how do I make this work?"

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using css for this using nth-of-type

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type

```
tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

but if you have to use javascript

```js
document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach((el, index) => {
  el.style = index % 2 === 0 ?
    'background-color: red' :
    'background-color: yellow';
})
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: OP asked *"How do I highlight every other row with % in JavaScript?"*.  This doesn't answer that.  I agree this will do the highlighting part, but it's not what they asked.  You should have just commented and clarified first.  As it stands, this is wrong.

Comment: I have commented awaiting reply will happily change my answer if he has a reason but are job is also to show OP how to do things correctly if his intentions are to style each row then doing it with % is verbose and incorrect if i have misunderstood his question then fair enough

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it, but I will have to use if(i%2 ==0) to solve this.

Comment: is there a reason for this i will happily help

Comment: Why do you need to use that if?

Comment: not necessarily "if", but I will have to use "%", sorry I didn't make it clear.

Comment: but why you havent said why. I've shown how to do it in my answer though

Comment: @ChrisChan Ok, let's assume that you HAVE to use the % operator. What do you mean by highlight? Do you mean having a different background color?

Comment: @AntonioNeto Yes, a different background color

Comment: Chris is there a reason you need to use the % instead of having a css class because if there isnt a reason i'd strongly suggest using css

Comment: @JoeWarner It is one part of my project, that required me to use % to highlight every other row of the table, I saw your answer, Thank you very much! but it somehow highlighted all of the rows except the last row.

Comment: I imagine you've got an even number of rows .

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few issues:

- You must put the `<td>` (cells) between the `<tr>` (rows). So you must open the `<tr>` at the beginning of the loop and close it at the end.
- You don't need the `cols` variable, you can use `head.length` or `Table[0].length`.
- You also don't need the `rows` variable, you can use `Table.length`.
- Inside your `<td>`, you add a `style` attribute and set the `background-color` to the color that you calculate based on your `%` condition.

```js
// declaring variables
var head = ['name', 'address', 'phone'];
var Table = [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90], [100, 200, 300]];

document.write('<table border="2">');

for (var k = 0; k < head.length; k++) {
  // input the heading of the table
  document.write('<th>' + head[k] + '</th>');
}

for (var i = 0; i < Table.length; i++) {
  document.write('<tr>');

  for (var j = 0; j < head.length; j++) {
    var bg = (i % 2 == 0) ? '#f00' : '#0ff';
    document.write('<td style="background-color: ' + bg + ';">' + Table[i][j] + '</td>');
  }
  document.write('</tr>');
}

document.write('</table>');
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much for pointing out, I did find that my code was kind of weird, but I just could not tell where.